# Sonatype Nexus 3rd Party Jar Not being pushed to Central

Tags: jar, jenkins, sonatype

I'm fairly unsure of Nexus - Our resident expert has departed (the project).

I've uploaded my 3rd party artifact via Nexus GUI. I can see that it is added to the 3rd party repository. When I build locally, My .m2 repository takes the jar, pom, source etc.. from Nexus and everything runs smoothly locally.

However Jenkins is failing because of a timeout

```
Downloading: http://66.66.66.66:8777/nexus/content/groups/public/net/sf/ehcache/ehcache-core/2.5.7/ehcache-core-2.5.7.pom
projectFailed ie.evince.dec:PROJ-NAME:66.6.66
```

I've had a look on Nexus and, although the jar is in the 3rd party Repository, when I expand net/sf/ehcache/ehcache-core/2.5.7 in the central repository , it just hangs there.

Not sure if this is related, but Central is 'Analyzing' - It has been Analyzing (blue) all afternoon (at least) - How can I cancel that?

Is there some way to force a push to central from 3rd Party?

I'm painfully aware that some of the stuff I just said may not make sense.

It's quite a closed environment in here. Nexus may not download jars automatically based on pom dependency. 3rd party jars must be uploaded manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a memory issue on the Nexus server. We got somebody to bounce, and everything is fine.